# Merging two columns should applicable to all pages in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a requirement where i need to read a file and display in Datagridview.

NOTE: A file contains 1000 lines but i have to show only 100 lines at the time of loading and after clicking on NEXT button it loads the next 100 lines. I'm done with this requirement and it's working fine.

I have a requirement to merge 2 columns on button click. After a button click, a new window will open where we do have an option to select the columns we are going to merge and displays in a Datagridview. When i'm doing that, it's merging the columns only on current page (i.e for only 100 lines) but i want it to be done for all pages (all 1000 lines).
    Can anyone resolve my issue? Below is the code i'm pasting for merging 2 columns:

FORM 1:

```
private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmMerge fs = new frmMerge(dataGridView1);
    fs.cmbColumn1.DataSource = cmbList;

    for (int i = 0; i <= cmbList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        fs.cmbColumn2.Items.Add(cmbList[i]);
    }
    fs.ShowDialog();
}
```

Browse button code (where i select the file and read it into datagridview):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Desktop";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "dat files (*.DAT)|*.DAT|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FileName);
        datfile = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            //Added on 2015-12-02
            maxRec = datfile.Length - 1;
            PageCount = maxRec / pageSize;
            LoadPage(MyFOrmat);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

FORM 2: (After clicking a MERGE button another window opens which contains merge button and combobox)

```
 private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvctime = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            dgvctime.Name = cmbColumn1.Text;
            dgvctime.HeaderText = cmbColumn1.Text;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvctime);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvctime);
            for (int i = 0; i <= dgvMerge.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[cmbColumn1.Text].Value = dgvMerge.Rows[i].Cells[cmbColumn1.Text].Value + " " + dgvMerge.Rows[i].Cells[cmbColumn2.Text].Value;
            }
        }

LOADPAGE:

  public void LoadPage(string Format, bool isFindAndReplace = false)
        {
            int startRec;
            int endRec;

            if (currentPage == PageCount)
            {
                endRec = maxRec;
            }
            else
            {
                endRec = pageSize * currentPage;
            }

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            if (recNo == 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            }

            int rowindex = 0;
            startRec = recNo;
            for (int RowCount = startRec; RowCount <= endRec; RowCount++)
            {
                if (datfile[RowCount].ToString() != "")
                {
                    if (RowCount == 0)
                    {
                        string[] column = datfile[RowCount].Split('þ');
                        for (int i = 0; i < column.Length - 1; i++)
                        {
                            if (column[i].ToString() != "" && column[i].ToString() != "\u0014")
                            {
                                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvtxtcountry = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                                dgvtxtcountry.HeaderText = column[i].ToString();
                                dgvtxtcountry.Name = column[i].ToString();
                                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvtxtcountry);
                                cmbList.Add(column[i]);
                                // dataGridView1.Columns["Sent Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                                i += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (RowCount != 0)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                        string[] column = datfile[RowCount].Split('þ');
                        int index = 0;
                        for (int i = 1; i < column.Length - 1; i++)
                        {
                            if (column[i].ToString() != "\u0014")
                            {
                                if (i == 3)
                                {
                                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(column[i]).ToString(Format);
                                }
                                else
                                { dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = column[i].Trim('þ'); }

                                if (isFindAndReplace && index == f.cmbColumnCombo.SelectedIndex)
                                {

                                    if ((column[i]).Contains(f.txtfind.Text))
                                        dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = column[i].Replace(f.txtfind.Text, f.txtreplace.Text);
                                }
                                index += 1;
                                i += 1;
                            }
                        }
                        rowindex += 1;
                    }
                }
                recNo += 1;
                //IsDateFormatted = false;
            }
        }

About MyFormat:

private void DateFormat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ComboBox objCombobox = (ComboBox)sender;
            MyFOrmat = objCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (recNo > 0)
                recNo = recNo - 30;
            LoadPage(MyFOrmat);
        }
```

Comment: You need to read the [mcve] link and post code that meets that requirement. Right now the really important stuff in your code is missing. Like what is `MyFOrmat`? Where is the code for `LoadPage`?

Comment: Don't just put `LoadPage`. Please make sure you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah i have deleted those comments and edited my query. I tried to minimize my query as per your comments. Sorry if it's sill not clear. But can you please try to help me out with this.